# In Haskell, [0.1..1] returns [0.1,1.1]. Why?

Tags: list, haskell

I am finding the list of `[0.1..1]` that will be returned from Haskell and I do not understand why it is `[0.1,1.1]`. Can anyone provide explanation for me please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TL;DR: don't use `[x..y]` on floating point numbers. You might get unexpected results.

On floating point numbers, there's no sane semantics for `[x..y]`. For instance, one might argue that the semantics should be `[x,x+1,x+2,...,x+n]` where `x+n` is the largest value of that form which is `<=y`. However, this does not account for floating point rounding errors. It is possible that `x+n` produces a slightly larger value than the exact `y`, making the list shorter than expected. Hence this semantics makes the value of `length [x..y]` rather unpredictable.

Haskell tries to mitigate this issue, by allowing an error up to `0.5`. The rationale is as follows: when `x+n` is closer to `y` than to `y+1`, it should be regarded as some value in the interval `[x..y]` which got rounded to something larger. Arguable, but this is how Haskell works.

In enumerations like `[x,y .. z]` with an explicit stepping (e.g. `[0.0,5.0 .. 1000.0]`) Haskell instead allows an error of `(y-x)/2` (`2.5` in the example). The rationale is the same: we include those points which are closer to `1000` than to `1000+5`.

You can find all the gory details in the [Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1310006.3.4) which defines the semantics of Haskell. [This part](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-400003.10) is also relevant.

This is generally seen by Haskellers as a small wart in the language. Some argue that we should not have mandated `Enum Float` and `Enum Double`. Removing those instances would effectively prohibit the troublesome cases like `[1.0 .. 5.0]` or the much worse `[1.0 .. 5.5]` (which is again numerically unstable).

Comment: Yes. The thing that _would_ actually make sense for `Float` is some `[x ..{n}.. y]` syntax as shorthand for `[x + k*(y-x)/n | k<-[0..n-1]]`, equivalent to `linspace` which is ubiquitous in the Matlab / NumPy etc. communities. Alternatively, `[x..y]` should denote the interval of _all_ numbers between `x` and `y`, but this is utterly impractical if the result has to be a list.

Comment: ...although, thinking of it, we could enumerate all the rationals in the interval... what could possibly go wrong... or `[x..y] = let m = (x+y)/2 in m : concat (zipWith (\x y->[x,y]) [x..m] [m..y])`

Comment: @leftaroundabout There are indeed several variants, each with its own ups and downs. I wonder if we really need to choose just one as "the" definition of `[x..y]` or simply leave `[x..y]` undefined and offer all the variants as library functions.

Comment: @leftaroundabout wouldn't `[x] ++ [x*(n-k)/n+y*k/n | k <-[1..n-1]] ++ [y]` be better? (for the `n > 0` case)

Comment: @WillNess or `[x + k*(y-x)/(n-1) | k<-[0..n-2]] ++ [y]`, which is actually what I meant (and is the default behaviour of `linspace`).

Comment: @leftaroundabout that does make more sense. :)

Comment: If float always a requirement? `[0.1 :: Rational, 0.2.. 1]` seems reasonable.

Comment: @pedrofurla I don't see any issues with `Rational` or any other numeric type having infinite precision (no rounding errors).

Comment: @chi Why do you have an issue with `[0.1 .. 1] :: [Double]` but not `[0.1 .. 1] :: Rational`? Their outputs are essentially identical (`[0.1, 1.1]` vs `[1%10, 11%10]`).

Comment: @DanielWagner Good point, I did not realize that rationals worked in such way too. Yuck. I now have an issue with both. Rationals are slightly better since `[0.5 .. 10.0]` is predictable, but that's still bad, IMO.

Comment: uh? Here I got `[1 % 10,1 % 5,3 % 10,2 % 5,1 % 2,3 % 5,7 % 10,4 % 5,9 % 10,1 % 1]`. Oh, my example had the second element defined.